# Display field, allow button to edit and save html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, user-input

I'm trying to create a page where a title and paragraph are displayed, along with an 'edit' button.

The goal is that the paragraph and title seems like normal text, but when the edit button is clicked, they become writeable fields that the user can edit. When the edits have been done, the user can click a save button and the html is updated.

Is this at all possible?

Furthermore, is it possible to have a 'create' button, that adds a new title and paragraph element that are blank, which the user can fill in?

I'd like to stick to html/javascript/jquery, since this won't be running on a server.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plugin exists already to provide in-place editing functionnality:

- [jQuery InPlace Editor](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-in-place-editor/)
- [jEditable](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable)

Comment: Thanks, jEditable seems a bit more complex, but it lets me write Html and have that apply, which is great!